# Return filenames from a list of files

Tags: php, regex

So I have a list of file names which I wish to pull to then put each one into an array.

Here is an example of the list I will be attempting to pull data from:

```
------------- 
PENDING: (fs) gm_construct.bsp 
PENDING: (fs) gm_flatgrass.bsp
...
```

Would a regular expression be able to parse through this list and just pull these bits:

```
gm_construct
gm_flatgrass
```

for example?

each entry would then need to be pushed into an array.

Would this expression also be able to run through a list much longer than this and also handle different prefixes like:

```
ttt_terrortown
```

Comment: Don't you think you could remove `PENDING: (fs)`, trim, and get  a substring up to the first `.`? No need for a regex.

Comment: Potentially. Would that work for all file names though? as this list would literally just be a long string.

Comment: Iterate through lines, only get those that start with `PENDING: (fs)`, and remove, trim, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end a friend came up with a little regex to do what I wanted. Might not be as simple as other answers, but it's the one I'm personally going to use, and works fine for my use case.

```
preg_match_all("/(?<=fs\)).*?(?=\.bsp)/", $maps, $map_list);
```

This did the trick for me. Splits each file name up into an array which I can then iterate through.

Answer (score 0):

pseudocode:

```
str.replaceAll("PENDING: (fs) ", "");
str.replaceAll(".bsp", "");
str.replaceAll("-", "");

str[] = str.split("\n");
```

the str[] will contain a list of your file names.

This basically replace all the "PENDING" stuff and the ".bsp" stuff and split the lines.

Hope this helps!

P.S., this does not require regex at all! (the easier the better)